# how to keep div center in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

using following bootstrap script my div. I need keep it center

```
 <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
```

How can I center this div class?

jsfiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/Lilan11/rr4npgg7/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
    .main {text-align: center}
```

This show center your form

Comment: actually I have a form in side this div (above) I need centered this form only.

Comment: Try text-align: center

Comment: I need center only My form not form text

Comment: If you could post the code in a jsfiddle this would give me a better idea. text-align: center, should center everything within the div

Comment: by using the parent div class main to use text-align: center. this should center the form instead of just the content of the form.